# get element from iframe

Tags: reactjs, iframe, cross-domain

in form tag passing an api in action and passing request for the api inside the form and after submitting the form, response from the api has been stored inside the form in string element.

Need to fetch out the content which is inside the string element after getting response from the api[in react]

```
 <iframe 
      width={"100%"}
      height={"850%"}
      position="absolute"
      id="3dSecure"
      name="3dSecure"
      src="http://localhost:5173/"
    >
      <form
        method="POST"
        action={threeDurl.VBVURL}
        id="latpayForm"
        target="3dSecure"
      >
        <input
          hidden
          name="PAReq"
          value={threeDurl.PAReq}
          readOnly={true}
        />
        <input
          hidden
          name="TermURL"
          value={threeDurl.TermURL}
          readOnly={true}
        />
```

I tried timeout method
var submitform = document.getElementById("testForm");

```
if (submitform) {
  submitform.submit();
  const timer = setTimeout(() => {
    const iframe = document.getElementById("3dSecure");

      var result = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("string")[0].innerHTML;
     console.log(result)
    
   
  }, 30000);
  return () => clearTimeout(timer);
}
```

in result getting cross-origin error